# Nested object in React functional component state with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an nested object in React functional component state, but I only can access first level of object if I use `any` type.

```
export default function Detail() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<any>({});
    const { id } = useParams();


    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/users/' + id)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            setUser(data);
        })
    }, []);
    
    

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Detail view</h1>
            <p>ID: { user.id }</p>
            <p>First name: { user.first_name }</p>
            <p>Last name: { user.last_name }</p>
            <p>Email: { user.email }</p>
            <p>Gender: { user.gender }</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

When trying to access `user.company.name` it throws

```
Detail.tsx:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

I made an interface for it, but it gives me an error if I'm trying to use it for state type.

```
interface UserInfo {
    id: number;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    email: string;
    gender: string;
    company: {
        name: string;
        department: string;
    }
}
```

```
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserInfo | (() => UserInfo)'.
```

How can I use defined interface as state type?

Comment: A quick fix is to use `{user.company && <p>{user.company.name}</p>}` to prevent the error. Not a typescript expert, but you probably need to assign an intial object that already has data for the interface properties. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745013/interface-states-and-props-in-typescript-react

Comment: also there is optional chaining. not sure if possible in Ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `any` type. TypeScript can't help you if you don't use actual types. Type the state narrowly.

Don't use an empty object as your default value. It isn't useful. Use a value that clearly indicates that the data isn't available yet.

---

```
type PossibleUserInfo = UserInfo | null;

const [user, setUser] = useState<PossibleUserInfo>(null);
```

---

Then, handle the case where you don't have the data yet explicitly.

It isn't useful to spit out a div with a bunch of paragraphs containing a label but not data.

---

```
if (user) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Detail view</h1>
            <p>ID: { user.id }</p>
            <p>First name: { user.first_name }</p>
            <p>Last name: { user.last_name }</p>
            <p>Email: { user.email }</p>
            <p>Gender: { user.gender }</p>
        </div>
    );
}

return (
    <div>
        <h1>Default view</h1>
        <Loading />
    </div>
);
```

… where `Loading` is a component that shows (for example) a [loading spinner](https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-react-loading-spinner-libraries).

Comment: I tried ```UserInfo | null``` before but it didn't worked, because I didn't used conditional statement on return. Now it works. Thanks